# Reference variable pointing to another object

Tags: java

There is an interface called `Bank`, and it has two implementing classes: `ABC` and `XYZ`.

```
public class Tester2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // i/f ref can directly refer to ANY concrete imple cls instance Bank
        ref = new ABC();// up casting
        ref.withdraw(123, 345);// DMD
        // ref.payBills(); 
        ((ABC) ref).payBills();
        ref = new XYZ();
        if (ref instanceof ABC)
            ((ABC) ref).payBills();
        else
            System.out.println("Wrong Bank!!!!");
    }
}
```

Now `ref` has type ABC and the value of `ref` is overridden by XYZ.  So how can the instance of ref be `ABC, considering`payBills`is a method in both the class`ABC`and`XYZ`?

Comment: please write your code as a code sample so that it's more legible

Comment: Where is the declaration for `ref`, `ABC`, `XYZ`, `Bank` etcetera,

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost, `ref` is a `Bank`.

```
Bank ref = new ABC();
```

Given that `Bank` is an interface, and `ABC` implements this interface, this is fine; this method is known as "programming to an interface".  So long as you refer to the class by the interface, you can interchangeably use any implementing subclass.

Next, you do a redundant cast to `ABC`:

```
((ABC) ref).payBills();
```

Since `ref` is backed by an instance of `ABC`, there's no value in performing this cast at all.

You then *reassign* `ref` to an instance of `XYZ`.  Again, this is legal in the same way that assigning to `ABC` is legal:

```
ref = new XYZ();
```

Now you do a strange `instanceof` check, in which we *know* that `ref` isn't backed by an instance of `ABC` but we check it anyway.  Remember:  you **reassigned** `ref`, so now it's backed by `XYZ`.

```
if (ref instanceof ABC)
```

The backing instance of `ref` in that statement will ***never*** be an instance of `ABC` after you've reassigned it to `XYZ`.

Comment: it can't? really?? so what happrns if you try to do it anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You've *already* tried to refer to it as an instance of `ABC` with the `instanceof` check.  After you reassign it to `XYZ`, it won't ever be an instance of `ABC`, which is why you see the message "Wrong Bank".

Comment: I am not OP.  what don't you understand in "what happens if you try to do it anyway" `instanceof` is **not** trying to refer, it is testing whether trying to refer will succeed or not.

Answer (score -1):

> Now `ref` has type `ABC` and the value of ref is overridden by `XYZ`.

No. This is very confused. `ref` remains of type `Bank`, and the object it refers to has become of type `XYZ`.

> So how can the instance of `ref` be `ABC`

It can't, after the assignment to `new XYZ()`.

> considering `payBills()` is a method in both the class `ABC` and `XYZ`?

Irrelevant.

Comment: it can't? really?? so what happrns if you try to do it anyway?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher That is correct. It can't. After the assignment to `new XYZ()`. In the OP's code. That we are discussing here. What happens if you try to do it anyway, by which I assume you mean the cast,  is a class cast exception. Obviously. Not in dispute, and not the question that was asked. Please stick to the point.

Comment: The question presented by OP was "how can the instance of ref be ABC" the answer IMO, should say if it can or cannot, why is it so and what happens if you try it anyway. just my way of working here

Comment: @SharonBenAsher 'The instance of `ref`' *isn't* `ABC`, as everybody has been saying, including you. There is nothing here or in your answer or your comments that makes this answer or the other one incorrect.

Comment: So if this answer is correct, what exactly is the purpose of your comment 'it can't? really?? so what happrns if you try to do it anyway?'

Comment: An answer can be correct and incomplete.  The purpose of the comment was straightforward: what happens if one tries to do the cast: is the cast legal or not?

Comment: @SharonBenAsher I've answered that, several times. The cast in the OP's code is legal. There is no question about casting in the OP.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand the question correctly, then the variables are declared:

```
interface Bank {}
class ABC implements Bank {}
class XYZ implements Bank {}
Bank ref;
```

If there is no inheritence relation between `ABC` znd `XYZ` then you cannot cast from one to the other.  This means that the if question will evaluate to false, otherwise you will get `ClassCastException` at run time.

EDIT:
as per the comments, Here is my try of the code. the If statement was omitted. 
 This is a complete working smaple you can copy-paste to your IDE:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank ref;
        // i/f ref can directly refer to ANY concrete imple cls instance Bank
        ref = new ABC();// up casting
        ref.withdraw(123, 345);// DMD
        // ref.payBills(); 
((ABC) ref).payBills();
        ref = new XYZ();
            ((ABC) ref).payBills();
    }

    public static interface Bank {
        void withdraw(int i, int j);
        void payBills();
    }

    public static class ABC implements Bank {

        @Override
        public void withdraw(int i, int j) {
            System.out.println("ABC");
        }
        @Override
        public void payBills() {
            System.out.println("ABC payBills");
        }
    }

    public static class XYZ implements Bank {

        @Override
        public void withdraw(int i, int j) {
            System.out.println("XYZ");
        }
        @Override
        public void payBills() {
            System.out.println("XYZ payBills");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ABC
ABC payBills
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: test.Test$XYZ cannot be cast to test.Test$ABC
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

Comment: If `ref` is a `Bank`, and both `ABC` and `XYZ` implement `Bank`, then the cast is seen as legal, since both `ABC` and `XYZ` are `Bank`s.

Comment: the cast will pass compilation but not runtime.  I fixed my answer. the if statement will evaluate to false.

Comment: No, it'll work just fine during runtime too.  This is what I mean by "legal" cast.

Comment: Certainly not. You've just changed the code to suit your answer. Try the *original* code.

Comment: @EJP, my answer specifies that the if statement will evaluate to false and that the exception will be thrown if it wasn't there.  and the cast is indeed **illegal** and will not pass at runtime

Comment: So? Nobody cares what happens if you remove the `if` statement. It is the OP's code that is under discussion here, not your travesty.

Comment: The question presented by OP was "how can the instance of ref be ABC" so I answered it fully and elaborated what would happen if one would try to "forcefully" do the cast.  You can argue that the elaboration is redundant.  However, the comments argued that my answer is incorrect - **but they are incorrect**

Comment: Your original answer claimed that the OP's code would fail at runtime. It doesn't. You subsequently modified the code in your answer to agree with that claim. This is not a respectable proceeding in science.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that the code from OP would not fail and in which conditions it would fail. and anyway, you evade my point that the comment about the legality of the cast was plainly incorrect

Comment: The 'comment about the legality of the cast' by @Makato was not incorrect with reference to the OP's code. Only to yours. You can't just change the question to agree with your answer.

Comment: then @Makoto should post the comment under the question, not the answer. It will be confusing for future viewers.  Anyway, I edited my answer to reflect OP original code and to explain exactly when an exception will be thrown

Comment: @Makoto's comment was about your original answer, not the OP's  question, which is the one thing you have avoided answering here, and your comment answering it remains incorrect.

Comment: my 2nd comment explains about my original and edited versions and why the cast is indeed illegal

Comment: It **isn't** illegal **in the OP's code,** as it is **protected by an `instanceof` check.** You **can't just change the question to suit your answer.** How many times does this need to be stated?